# Get The Phone TabBar Size without any TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to get the tabbar default size but I don't have any tabBar in `ViewController` so I didnt get with `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height` .

**Where I use:**

I have a container view(it creates with `ViewController`) and it includes a `collectionview`. And I want to give an `footer` height because of main ViewController has an `tabBar` so I have to give an height as much as `tabBar size`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of tabbar from main VC and save it to some global variable and then you can use it anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If **tabBarController** is your root view controller, then :

```
let rootController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController  // Main ViewController  
let height = rootController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
```